# .NET CLI (dotnet) Build : exclude project from solution

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, build, teamcity

TeamCity
.NET CLI (dotnet) Build

Building a Visual Studio Solution ( .sln ) with multiple Projects ( .csproj ).

Is it possible to exclude a certain project from the build ?

This is a project no other projects depend on.

Comment: Are you using the `dotnet build` command? Are you using a `Command Line`-step or their buit-in `.NET CLI (dotnet)`-step?

Comment: This is from the `TeamCity UI` so I'm using the built-in `.NET CLI (dotnet)` step.

Answer (score 4):

You need [`dotnet sln` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln).
But according to the [documentation of TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/net.html#Build+Runner+Options) it does not support it yet.

But you can try to use a `Projects` option with a wildcard:

```
!**/ProjectToExclude.csproj
```

Or may be you should use [Docker Wrapper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/docker-wrapper.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new solution configuration or just change a existing one.

To create a solution configuration that excludes a project
On the menu bar, choose Build > Configuration Manager.

In the Active solution configuration list, choose .

In the Name box, enter a name for the solution configuration.

In the Copy settings from list, choose the solution configuration on which you want to base the new configuration (for example, Debug), and then choose the OK button.

In the Configuration Manager dialog box, clear the check box in the Build column for the project that you want to exclude, and then choose the Close button.

On the Standard toolbar, verify that the new solution configuration is the active configuration in the Solution Configurations box.

On the menu bar, choose Build > Rebuild Solution.

If you're executing in command line 'dotnet build --configuration Release' I suggest to change to:
1 - 'dotnet restore';
2 - 'dotnet --no-restore --configuration Release'